# How we got $z\cdot(x+y)=x\cdot y$

Tags: proof-writing, alternative-proof

This is from "Test of math at 10+2 level":

> A vessel contains $x$ gallons of wine and another contains $y$ gallons of water. From each vessel $z$ gallons are taken out and transferred to the other. From the resulting mixture in each vessel, $z$ gallons are again taken out and transferred to the other. If after a second transfer, the quantity of wine in each vessel remains the same as it was after the first transfer, then show that $z\cdot(x+y)=x\cdot y.$

**My Try:**$$\text{Originally:}\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Vessel:} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
\text{Wine} & x & 0 \\ \hline
\text{Water} & 0 & y \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{After first transfer:}\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Vessel:} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
\text{Wine} & x-z & z \\ \hline
\text{Water} & z & y-z \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{After second transfer:}\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Vessel:} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
\text{Wine} & x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z & z+\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z \\ \hline
\text{Water} & z-\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot z & y-z+\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot z \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
And because, the quantity of wine in each vessel remains the same as it was after the first transfer, $$x-z=x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z\tag1,$$$$z=z+\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z\tag2,$$ which implies $x=z$. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.  That means that at any step, you should be able to reverse:
1) $x$ and $y$
2) Wine and Water
3) vessel 1 and vessel 2
And the result is the exact same relation.

You can also check at each step that wine in vessel1 plus water in vessel1 is x, and that wine in vessel2 plus water in vessel2 is y.

Notice that after the second transfer, the triple reverse doesn't give you back the same equation.  The sums do not work out either.  That tells you where a mistake is.

$$
\text{After second transfer:}\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Vessel:} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
\text{Wine} & 
x-z-\underbrace{\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z}_{\text{loss of wine}} 
+ \underbrace{\frac z y z}_{\text{gain of wine}} &
 z+\underbrace{\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z}_{\text{gain of wine}} - \underbrace{\frac z y z}_{\text{loss of wine}} \\ \hline
\text{Water} & 
z-\underbrace{\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot z}_{\text{Loss of water}} + \underbrace{\frac z y (y - z)}_{\text{Gain of water}} &
y-z+\underbrace{\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot z}_{\text{Gain of water}}  - \underbrace{\frac z y (y - z)}_{\text{Loss of water}} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

From the wine amount being the same in the first vessel:

$$x - y = x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z + \frac z y z \tag{Wine is same in vessel 1}$$

$$x - y = x-z-z+\frac{z^2} x + \frac {z^2} y$$

$$2z = y +\frac{z^2} x + \frac {z^2} y$$

$$2 = \frac y z +\frac{z} x + \frac {z} y \tag{R1}$$

As it turns out, $R1$ isn't necessary to solve the problem.  Sometimes that happens, you get extra information.  Let's look at the second vessel.

Edit: there is a mistake in the initial equation, it should be $x - z = $ rather than $x - y =$ so a corrected form of R1 is useful.

$$ z = z+\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z - \frac z y z \tag{Wine is same in vessel 2}$$

$$ z = z+z-\frac{z^2}{x} - \frac {z^2} y$$

$$ z = \frac{z^2}{x} + \frac {z^2} y$$

$$ 1 = \frac{z}{x} + \frac {z} y$$

$$x \cdot y = z \cdot(x + y)$$

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer and correcting. Shall I too correct you? Note that in R1, you started from $x - y = x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z + \frac z y z$, instead of $x - z = x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)\cdot z + \frac z y z$. If you would have done so, R1 also would have yield $x \cdot y = z \cdot(x + y)$ and no "non-useful" equation arises.

Comment: Also, will you please explain why the problem is symmetric?

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  As for the symmetry, consider this.  Take the question itself, and switch $x$ with $y$, vessel 1 with vessel 2, and water with wine.  Notice that you get back the exact same question, just stated in a different order.  If you can switch them around in the question and get the same question, then you should able to switch them around in any conclusion and get the same conclusion.  Noticing this kind of pattern in problems is a bit like fashion sense, you just get a feeling for "this part is just like that part with things switched around".

Comment: @DanielV Does the fact that we write amount of wine in second transfer as $x-z-\left(\frac{x-z}{x}\right)z$ assume that the resulting mixture is uniform, cause if it weren't, we would have to assume different amounts of water and wine being transferred that sum upto $z$ gallons in respective vessels?

Comment: @ParasKhosla Yes I think you should presume that the mixture is uniformly mixed, otherwise the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: @DanielV Alright. Thanks for clarifying.